# Solr facet field results in json are appearing as comma separated list rather than dictionary

Tags: solr

I'm doing a simple facet search:

`/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=fruit`

Using Solr 5.0.0 lucene.

The correct values are found, however the json format doesn't make sense. The values for "fruit" are displayed in a comma separated list where I would expect them to appear in a dictionary.

In json I see the following:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 3,
        "params": {
            "q": "*:*",
            "facet.field": "fruit",
            "indent": "true",
            "rows": "0",
            "wt": "json",
            "facet": "true"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 360,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": []
    },
    "facet_counts": {
        "facet_queries": {},
        "facet_fields": {
            "fruit": [
                "apple", 200,
                "banana", 34,
                "orange", 126]
        },
        "facet_dates": {},
        "facet_ranges": {},
        "facet_intervals": {}
    }
}
```

The same search in xml shows the following:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">5</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="q">*:*</str>
            <str name="facet.field">fruit</str>
            <str name="indent">true</str>
            <str name="rows">0</str>
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
            <str name="facet">true</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="360" start="0"> </result>
    <lst name="facet_counts">
        <lst name="facet_queries"/>
        <lst name="facet_fields">
            <lst name="fruit">
                <int name="apple">200</int>
                <int name="banana">34</int>
                <int name="orange">126</int>
            </lst>
        </lst>
        <lst name="facet_dates"/>
        <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
        <lst name="facet_intervals"/>
    </lst>
</response>
```

I would expect the json facet count to appear like this:

```
"fruit": [
    "apple": 200,
    "banana": 34,
    "orange": 126]
```

I've never encountered this before with other facet searches, would this be something caused by something in the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here two solution of your requirement.

**1. Use latest or 7.x and above Solr so you can easily get it as below explanation**

First refer [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/json-facet-api.html) link

You can achieve your output via using json facet query.

Instead  of this

```
/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=fruit
```

Please try with below query.

```
/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&json.facet={fruits:{type:terms, field:fruit}}
```

For more knowledge of facet query please refer [this](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/) article

**2. Response Writers**

Here I am not sure it's supported into Solr 5.0.0.

refer [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/response-writers.html)  for more into response writer.

You can change your response into any custom format using response writers in solr.